# Puppeteer-cluster close browsers itself

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

I use puppeteer-cluster + node js. I have some script.
I'm a newbie

The script runs halfway through and then ends and is not executed further. I've been looking for a solution for a week now, I don't understand what's the matter. Help me please enter code here

```js
const { Cluster } = require('puppeteer-cluster-delay');

(async () => {
    const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
        concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_CONTEXT,
        maxConcurrency: 2,
        puppeteerOptions: {headless: false,
        },
    });

    await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: url }) => {
        await page.goto('http://www.google.com/');
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => { // user is waiting for an asynchronous event
                try {
                    resolve();
                } catch (err) {
                    // handle error
                }
            }, 5000);
        });
        await console.log('1');
        await page.goto('http://www.google.com/');
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => { // user is waiting for an asynchronous event
                try {
                    resolve();
                } catch (err) {
                    // handle error
                }
            }, 5000);
        });
        await console.log('2');
        await page.goto('http://www.google.com/');
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => { // user is waiting for an asynchronous event
                try {
                    resolve();
                } catch (err) {
                    // handle error
                }
            }, 5000);
        });
        await console.log('3');
        await page.goto('http://www.google.com/');
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => { // user is waiting for an asynchronous event
                try {
                    resolve();
                } catch (err) {
                    // handle error
                }
            }, 5000);
        });
        await console.log('4');
        await page.goto('http://www.google.com/');
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => { // user is waiting for an asynchronous event
                try {
                    resolve();
                } catch (err) {
                    // handle error
                }
            }, 5000);
        });
        await console.log('5');
        await page.goto('http://www.nike.com/');
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => { // user is waiting for an asynchronous event
                try {
                    resolve();
                } catch (err) {
                    // handle error
                }
            }, 5000);
        });
        await console.log('6');
        await page.goto('http://www.google.com/');
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => { // user is waiting for an asynchronous event
                try {
                    resolve();
                } catch (err) {
                    // handle error
                }
            }, 5000);
        });
        await console.log('7');
        await page.goto('http://www.google.com/');
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => { // user is waiting for an asynchronous event
                try {
                    resolve();
                } catch (err) {
                    // handle error
                }
            }, 5000);
        });
        await console.log('8');
        await page.goto('http://www.google.com/');
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => { // user is waiting for an asynchronous event
                try {
                    resolve();
                } catch (err) {
                    // handle error
                }
            }, 5000);
        });
        await console.log('end');
    });

    await cluster.queue();
    await cluster.queue();
    // many more pages

    await cluster.idle();
    await cluster.close();
})();
```

the script reaches the 5th iteration and ends ((

Answer (score 0):

We need to use timeout argument in launching puppeteer.
Set timeout = 0 to off ones

Answer (score 0):

```
cluster.on("taskerror", async (err, data) => {
    console.log(`Error crawling ${data}: ${err.message}`);
});
```

Add this function to your main `async function`. It is an event listener for error, once your script crashes it will display the error and you can troubleshoot it. With the code you have as it is you won't be able to tell what happened with your script. But, by the looks of it the queue timeouts as the default is 30000ms I believe and your script definitely takes longer than that to complete.

Inside the `cluster.launch()` arguments pass `timeout: 0` for unlimited or however long you need.